# Can`t expose port for node express app in Centos7 container

Tags: node.js, docker, centos

I am creating an image node HTTP server app. App run on 3000 port. But I can`t reach it from localhost.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
RUN yum install -y nodejs
RUN node -v
#yarn
RUN curl --silent --location https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo | tee /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo
RUN rpm --import https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/pubkey.gpg
RUN yum install -y yarn
# Set up mongodb yum repo entry
RUN echo -e "\
[mongodb-org-4.0]\n\
name=MongoDB Repository\n\
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/7/mongodb-org/4.0/x86_64/\n\
gpgcheck=1\n\
enabled=1\n\
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc\n" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo

# Install mongodb
RUN yum update -y && yum install -y mongodb-org

COPY server.js /home/server.js
COPY start.sh  /home/start.sh
COPY package.json  /home/package.json

# Install js dependencies
RUN cd /home
RUN yarn

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/home/start.sh"]
```

start.sh:

```
echo "HELLO FROM SH FILE!"
yarn

node ./server.js
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

For build container I use:

`docker build -t "gepick:dev1" .`

For start container I use:

`docker run -i -t 2f0fd105f299 -p 3000:3000 /bin/bash`

I sure that app is up and running because console output is:

`Example app listening on port 3000!`

But when I try to run app throw browser on localhost:3000 I get:

`This site can’t be reached`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is it `docker run -i -t 2f0fd105f299 -p 3000:3000 /bin/bash` ???

Your launch command should be

```
docker run -i -t -p 3000:3000 2f0fd105f299
```

Puting exposal arguments after image ID just passes them to your `start.sh` script. Docker only reads arguments before image name/ID.